# Turning on off a php function to echo slideshow from Wordpress backend

Tags: php, wordpress

What is the easiest way to create a backend checkbox to turn on and off a php echo call like:

```
    <?php echo get_template_part( 'partials/slider/test-slider' ); ?>
```

?

Comment: click a link that sets a query parameter. your server-side code stores that paramter in a session somewhere, and looks for it if/when you're building the page, and decides what to do at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Wordpress option!

As seen from [WordPress's API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)

```
// Fetch a saved option - Call this on your PHP echo page.
get_option( $option, $default = false );

// this goes on your themes SETTINGS page, on save of form
update_option( $option, $newvalue );
```

In your theme settings code:

```
// return variable to show proper setting on form
<?php $show_slideshow = get_option('show_slideshow'); ?>

<div id="first-option" class="option-container">
    <label class="backend-title">Turn On Slideshow</label>
    <div class="setting">
       <input name="show_slideshow" value="" type="checkbox" />
    </div>


</div>
```

Above the form on the theme settings page:

```
if(isset($_POST['show_slideshow'])) {

    $data = stripslashes_deep($_POST);

    $setting = $data['show_slideshow'];

    update_option('show_slideshow', $setting);

}
```

Comment: HI, thx. After inserting the first part of the code into the functions.php the site went blank - dont work...?

Comment: @NewUser turns out you don't need the first part.  I edited my answer.  I'm not showing everything required, but this generally covers how to update options.